# Conda in Julia create new Environment inside an Environment directory, how to change it?

Tags: python, julia, conda

I am using Julia-1.7.3
I type this:

```
julia> ]

pkg> add Conda

julia> using Conda
julia> Conda.add("matplotlib", :nagienv)
```

Then I get this:

[ Info: Running **`conda create -y -p /home/browni/.julia/conda/3/envs/pyplot_env/envs/nagienv`** in root environment
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Before it was
**`conda create -y -p /home/browni/.julia/conda/3/envs/nagienv`**

what should I do to change the target directory for new environment?

I try to set Python Env  and build PyCall :

```
julia> ENV["PYTHON"] = "/home/browni/.julia/conda/3/bin/python3"
julia> using PyCall
julia> ]

pkg> build PyCall
```

it is still creating environment inside an environment directory.
I just want a tidier folder structure. Thanks.